# Can I take an ant on a plane from Albania to a EU country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, legal, eu, insects

This might be a weird question, but as an antkeeper I'm curious about any rules regarding bringing ants on a plane. In this particular case: on a flight from Albania to Belgium, but any broader answer is also very helpful.

I tried checking all the prohibitions on major airlies in the EU, but could find no rules regarding insects in luggage. Nor could I find any EU restrictions on import of insects. So if it were just me, I'd take the risk and bring'm with me, and if I get questions I'd just try to explain what I'm doing. However... in this case it's not me who's traveling to Albania, but a close friend of mine who wants to take some ants home for me. To make matters even worse: that friend is a teacher accompanying a group of kids. I do NOT want her to get into trouble with customs while boarding the plane. That'd be a catastrophe.

So I wonder where I could find the rules regarding bringing ants on a plane from Albania to a EU country. I'm assuming there's three things I need to keep in mind:

- export laws (and wildlife preservation laws) of Albania
- import laws (and biosecurity laws) of the EU country of destination (Belgium in this case)
- prohibitions of items in luggage of the airline

Yet, I'm struggling to find info. And also from fellow antkeepers I'm struggling to find information.

Some extra remarks, because I'm expecting concerned responses to this question:

- The ant will be contained in a test tube. It will not be able to escape.
- As antkeepers, obviously we are aware that bringing invasive species over can be damaging to the environment, and this is something we always keep in mind. Measures will be taken, even though in this case (Albania->BE) the risk is minimal.
- I think a lot of users of this website are US-citizens. In the US the laws regarding this topic are very clear, and are very strict. However, keep in mind that in the EU this is not the case. Sale of ants (even across borders) is not prohibited and perfectly legal. There's a couple of EU countries (such as Spain) that have some additional laws, but even those do not pose an actual barrier when shipping ants to other EU countries).

Comment: I think in this case the rule 'never bring anything for someone else across a border' should count and you should not ask that teacher when traveling with a group of kids. Still a good question, +1.

Comment: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/animal-plant/index_en.htm confims that it's entirely down to national law so your research should focus on Belgium specifically.

Comment: FWIW, Brussels Airlines claims that insects must be shipped as cargo: "All animals, other than cats and dogs, must be shipped as cargo in accordance with the IATA Live Animals Regulation." This IATA publication is not freely available, so I can't verify what exactly it is saying, but if IATA disallows other animals but cats and dogs to travel as 'regular' luggage, other airlines are also likely to follow that Lufthansa is also, for the transport of other animals but cats and dogs, referring to Lufthansa Cargo.

Comment: I'd be highly surprised if it's allowed. Countries constantly combat invading species, and invading insects were known to cause great damages, e.g. [fire ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_imported_fire_ant)

Comment: @ugoren That's what most people say. In practice I can't find any official document that clearly states the laws that forbid what I'm describing. 
It is true that there's a bunch of invasive species, and that nearly every country in the world is trying to prevent it, but... in the EU there are ant- and insect shops in nearly every country. And they also sell Solenopsis invicta (Red imported fire ant)... (1/2)

Comment: But to be honest, I also don't really get the hysteria about [Solenopsis invicta](https://www.antwiki.org/wiki/Solenopsis_invicta). There's species that are WAY more invasive than them, such as [Pheidole megacephala](https://www.antwiki.org/wiki/Pheidole_megacephala) and [Tetramorium bicarinatum](https://www.antwiki.org/wiki/Tetramorium_bicarinatum).
Anyways, this is getting off-topic. I was asking about laws and potential practical problems one might encounter. I'm well aware of what invasive species are, what risk they pose, and how to handle them. (2/2)

Comment: You may know what you're doing very well. But import rules likely assume that you don't, and expect you to jump through some hoops to prove that your ants pose no risk.

Comment: @ugoren that's precisely what this question is about: the import rules. Everyone says they exist. But no one seems to be able to show me a document where they are listed. 
And also the fact that nearly every antshop in the EU sells invasive species for less than a beer makes me wonder if there's really rules about it. I can hardly believe that all those shops are breaking the law?
This is in big contrast with the US: laws are very strict and clear. And only shops with a permit are allowed to ship across state borders, and even then the number of species are limited.

Comment: Hopefully ant shops get all required import approvals. Or maybe the ants just ignore the rules and crawl into the owner's carry-on when they're abroad.

Comment: I would suggest that "can't escape" be modified to "shouldn't be able to escape"

Comment: Perhaps they're concerned about [this situation](https://youtu.be/HOOY43LQFus?t=2192).

Comment: The best question ever on the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to involve significant bureaucracy.

[www.health.belgium.be](https://www.health.belgium.be/en/animals-and-plants/animals/animal-keeping-and-transporting/travelling-pets#Travelling%20with%20other%20pet%20animals) says:

> In Belgium, there are no specific rules for travelling with other pet
> animals than dogs, cats and ferrets. However, when the animals come
> from a non-EU-country, you should submit an application for permission
> to import to the Federal Agency for the Safety of the Food Chain
> through import@afsca.be.
>
> For travelling with exotic animals, you must also comply with the
> CITES regulation.

[fasfc.be](https://www.fasfc.be/import-belgiumlive-animals-and-germinal-products/import-controls) contains various info, including:

> Each consignment of live animals must be notified by an interested
> party to the FASFC at the BIP of arrival at least one working day
> before its expected arrival on EU territory. The pre-notification must
> be made by means of a Common Veterinary Entry Document, the CVED, via
> the TRACES system.  A CVED must be drawn up for each consignment, the
> model of which is laid down in Regulation (EC) N° 282/2004.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was indeed the information I was looking for! Strange thing I had such a hard time finding it myself.
Upvoted and will accept answer in 24h (as per SE etiquette). 
Do you maybe also have information about possible export rules in Albania? 
Extra internet points if you could add that, because I can't upvote and accept twice :)